# is there any solution to PHP query based on the echo value

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to count the username column (distinct) from "user" table based on the project_title that i got from "project" table, on the "project" table i have column with username as on the user table

The Project Name has successfully displayed, but i was not successfully to count the username number based on the project name,

Below is the code i used

```
<tbody>
<?php 
    $no = 1;
    $data = mysqli_query($connect,"select * from project");
    while($d=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
    ?>
        <tr style="text-align:center;">
            <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
            <td style="width:125px;" name="title"><?php echo $d['project_title']; ?></td>

                <?php
                $topice = $_GET['title'];
                foreach($connect->query("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (username)) FROM user where topic='$topice'") as $row) {
                    echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(DISTINCT (username))'] . "</td>";
                }
                ?>

        </tr>
        <?php 
    }
?>
</tbody>
```

Expected to get the username count of WinBali = 3 and WinITB = 2

Based on MySQL Data

Comment: I believe your table structure is wrong. You should have one table for users and another table for users_count(Eg likes, votes, rating etc). when you perform query on the user table then iterating users_count table becomes easy. Alternatively, if you want a junkey way. you can create users table with a column eg user_count. This will require your application to query the last users count and perform updates each time count button is clicked

Comment: @NancyMooree i am sorry to not make it clear, so i have 2 tables, first is user table which is containing 2 column, username and project_title, and second table is project table . which is containing 1 column project_title

Comment: You must have more columns than that...where does the "topic" column come from otherwise? Please give a clear and complete description of your data structure, provide some sample row data and then tell us about exactly what result you want to see from your code

Comment: I can help you just stay tight

Comment: See me answer and give me a shout if you like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you insight on how to create tables and run your applications

```
create table nancy_project(project_id int primary key auto_increment,project_title varchar(30),project_name varchar(30),username varchar(30));


create table nancy_user(user_id int primary key auto_increment,username varchar(30),project_id varchar(30),counter int(11));
```

**You can now insert**

```
insert into nancy_project(project_title,project_name,username) values('Chemistry Project','This is for Chemistry lecturers','WinBali');
insert into nancy_project(project_title,project_name,username) values('Physics Project','This is for Physics stsudents','WinITB');
```

Remember That **project_id** is auto incremented starting from 1 and so not included in the insert statements

**Counting made by WinBali = 3  on project id 1**

```
insert into nancy_user(username,project_id,counter) values('WinBali',1,1);
insert into nancy_user(username,project_id,counter) values('WinBali',1,1);
insert into nancy_user(username,project_id,counter) values('WinBali',1,1);
```

**counting made by WinITB = 2 on project id 2**

```
insert into nancy_user(username,project_id,counter) values('WinITB',2,1);
insert into nancy_user(username,project_id,counter) values('WinITB',2,1);
```

**Note:** You will query by **project_id** and not **project_title** unless you will make sure that project title will be unique.

Here is the code

```
     <?php

$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "root"; /* User */
$password = ""; /* Password */
$dbname = "dbname goes here"; /* Database name */

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$con) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


               //$username ='WinBali';
               //$username ='WinITB';
                $query = "SELECT * FROM nancy_project";
                $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                    $project_id = $row['project_id'];
                    $project_title = $row['project_title'];
                    $project_name = $row['project_name'];
                        $username = $row['username'];

                    // Count the counter
// you can try different queries commented
$query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cntStatus FROM nancy_user where username='$username' and project_id='$project_id'";
                    //$query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cntStatus FROM nancy_user where username='$username'";
                    $result1 = mysqli_query($con,$query1);
                    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
                    $total_count = $row1['cntStatus'];


            ?>
                    <div class="post">
 <h1 style="color:green"><?php echo $username; ?></h1>
                        <h1><?php echo $project_title; ?></h1>
                        <div class="post-text">
                            <?php echo $project_name; ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-action">

                            (<span><?php echo $total_count; ?></span>)<br>


                        </div>
                    </div>
            <?php
                }
            ?>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here is the screenshot of the result**

[image: screenshot]

Remember to perform sanitization and validations when request is coming from form inputs to avoid vulnerabilities like **sql injections, csrf, xss, html injections** etc.